# Passing objects to a gui in java

Tags: java, user-interface, object

I'm currently in a java class and I'm trying to work on build a my first interface. The one below is not the one I'm working on, but a test one so I can figure out how to do what I want to do. Here is the code, the question will follow:

```
package test;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
*
 * @author StrifeX
 */
public class Test {

public static class buttonTest extends JFrame {

    private int number;

    private JButton push;

    public ButtonTest(){



        setLayout(new GridBagLayout ());

        //Creates an instance of the layout
        GridBagConstraints panel = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Establishes the pixels suronding each object within the layout
        panel.insets = new Insets (5, 5, 5, 5);

        //create the withdraw button and its properties
        push = new JButton("push");
        panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.gridx = 0;
        panel.gridy = 0;
        panel.gridwidth = 1;
        add(push, panel);

        MyEvent buttonClick = new MyEvent();

        push.addActionListener(buttonClick);

    }//end constructor

    public class MyEvent implements ActionListener {


        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent buttonClick){
        String operation = buttonClick.getActionCommand();

            if(operation.equals("Withdraw")){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "test" );

            }
        }   

    }

}//end button test


public static class TestObject{

int testField;

public void testObject(){

     testField = 10;

}

public void setterMethod(int newInt){

    this.testField = newInt;

}

public int getterMethod(){

    return this.testField;

}


}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TestObject obj1 = new TestObject();
    buttonTest button = new buttonTest();




    // Establish basic parameters for the GUI 
    button.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.setSize(450, 350);
    button.setTitle("Change the Balance");

}
}
```

What I want to do is build an object, then use that objects methods with the GUI button. I can build the object, and pass it to the constructor that make the GUI (buttonTest), but the Event class cant see that object, and from the little I know, I can't pass it to the event class, but maybe the actionPerformed method like this:

`public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent buttonClick, testObject thing)`

However, when I tried to do that, I received and error that said

> buttonTest.event is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   actionPerformed(actionEvent) in ActionListener.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: public class Event implements ActionListener: change the Event--
>MyEvent

Comment: Small point but please try to conform to the Java code conventions: `static class buttonTest` classes should start with a capital letter, including inner ones.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will make sure to stick to the conventions next time I post, I hadn't done it here because it was test code.

Comment: Changing your class Event--->MyEvent, should work. have you checked

Comment: It's a courtesy to anyone reading your code, even us folks here.  Re. I. Ahmed's point, using an `include *` includes all classes, and in `java.awt.*` you get the `java.awt.Event` class, which is conflicting with your class `Event`.  In general, any use of `include *` is not best practice, again even in "test code."

Comment: I changed Event to MyEvent. However, what was that supposed to correct? I still can't pass an object to the actionPerformed method without getting that error. As for the use of the imports, the only reason I used those the way they are is because of the example the professor provided. I tried to comment out java.awt.event.*, but that caused errors. If I remove any of the imports it causes errors. I made some corrections to the formatting as well.

Comment: Also action performed take the parameter as follows:public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e). Not two parameter

Comment: Pass `TestObject` to `ButtonTest` (via the constructor), pass `TestObject` to `MyObject` (via the constructor)

Comment: I assume you mean "MyEvent". But if I try to pass it into the construction of my event like so: `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClick, testObject thing)`, I get the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wrongly defined the following:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent buttonClick, testObject thing)
```

The correct definition will be:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent buttonClick)
```

Comment: I have it as that way. Adding "testObject thing" did give me an error. But that is not the issue i am trying to solve. In this code:

    `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "test" );`

I want to replace "test" with an object and its method. How do I get an object in there?

Comment: public static class buttonTest extends JFrame {
   ////Your object goes here///
    private int number;
   
    private JButton push; Then your inner class can access it

Comment: So when creating GUI's, should object creation or reading in data go into the GUI creation class instead of the main method?

Comment: Its better to add the data in class, rather than main method. Main method is for application entry point. Not for adding redundant code there.

Answer (score 0):

Getting passed all your previous issues and getting to the heart of the question

> Passing objects to a gui in java

You basically need to pass the `TestObject` to all the classes which need access to it.

Start by modifying your `MyEvent` class to take a reference to `TestObject`

```
public class MyEvent implements ActionListener {

    private TestObject obj;

    public MyEvent(TestObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonClick) {
        String operation = buttonClick.getActionCommand();

        // Now you have acces to obj

        if (operation.equals("Withdraw")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");

        }
    }

}
```

This will require you to modify your `ButtonTest` class to allow it to pass the `TestObject` through to the event handler...

```
public static class ButtonTest extends JFrame {
    //...
    public ButtonTest(TestObject obj) {
        //...
        MyEvent buttonClick = new MyEvent(obj);
        //...
```

And finally, you create and pass the object to the instance of `ButtonTest` which needs it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestObject obj1 = new TestObject();
    ButtonTest button = new ButtonTest(obj1);

    // Establish basic parameters for the GUI 
    button.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.setSize(450, 350);
    button.setTitle("Change the Balance");

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This clarified it for me. Being new to this, I was under the impression that most of your coding was going to happen in the main method. However, it appears that it will be the external classes.